# T sql find same values and order by

Tags: sql-server

I have table `Customer` with these columns:

```
sales_ID varchar(50)
product_ID int
ProcessNumber int
CreateDate datetime
```

and this sample data:

```
sales_Id       product_id    ProcessNumber
---------------------------------------------  
00000020041       1733           15
00000020041       1733           15    
00000020041       1733           15
```

**Question:**

If I use this query

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
        *,
        row_number() over(PARTITION BY sales_Id, product_ID, ProcessNumber
                          ORDER BY xdate) rown
     from Customer) tbl 
where 
     rown > 1 
order by 
     sales_ID
```

Results:

```
1. 00000020041      1733       15
```

But I want query to display this result

```
 1. 00000020041      1733       15
 2. 00000020041      1733       15
 3. 00000020041      1733       15
```

What to change in my query according to select all duplicates values (2 rows , 3 rows , 4 rows...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` to `COUNT(*) OVER()`, e.g.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                    CountOfRowsInGroup = COUNT(*) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY sales_Id,product_ID,ProcessNumber)
            FROM    Customer
        ) AS tbl
WHERE   CountOfRowsInGroup > 1
ORDER BY Sales_ID;
```

This will return all duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Look up RANK and DENSE_RANK. I better reword that as it's misleading: If you had 3 duplicates for RANK records might be numbered 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6 etc. If you had 3 duplicates for DENSE_RANK you'd get 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.